# why my forms are not working in bootstrap website?

Tags: php, html, forms

I tried all but no form is working with method or simple action like http://google.com `

```
<form action="http://google.com" method="post">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

even this is not working

Comment: ... What? What do you mean by "not working"? Do you know how a form is suppose to work?

Comment: Your inputs have no `name=""` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**use this**

`<form role="form" action="http://google.com" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>`

1. role attribute for FORM
2. name attribute for input

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, $_POST always accept `name` attribute from form elements:-

You need to write

```
<input type="text" name='name_of_your_field' />
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" />
```

You need to refer this [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).